# How can I change the profile icon on NuGet.Org

Tags: nuget, user-profile, avatar

How can I change the gravatar associated with my nuget.org profile? I have noticed other users have photo's as their avatar.

I have created a profile on nuget.org and uploaded a package.

Comment: just created a gravatar account under the email I used for nuget.org. until now, no change observed

Comment: thx mauricio - it did not work immediately, i created a gravatar account with the matching email but tested with the default gravatar image. one however has to upload a custom icon to make it working. finally cache clearing (as gravatar hints) was necessary. now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NuGet Gallery uses [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) for profile images. You must create a Gravatar account using the *same* email address you used on the NuGet Gallery. We unfortunately don't make this very clear; we have an [open issue](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/423) to better explain this.

Comment: thank you! - yes, adding a short note in the profile edit page could save some time to package authors